# Incorrect output from windows 10 command prompt

Tags: c++, file, input, cygwin, command-prompt

Where C++ compiler is **Cygwin** with **gcc version 8.3.0**

The following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cin.tie(0);
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);

    cout << "START" << endl;

    int x;
    string a, b;
    getline(cin, a);
    cin >> x; cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, b);
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << b << endl;
    cout << x << endl;

    cout << "END" << endl;
```

from Windows 10 **command prompt** *command*:

```
g++ sol.cpp && a.exe < in.txt
```

and **in.txt** is a file:

```
Lorem Ipsum
5
Hello World
```

prints **INCORRECT OUTPUT**

```
START
Lorem Ipsum

5
END
```

instead of **CORRECT OUTPUT**

```
START
Lorem Ipsum
Hello World
5
END
```

while the same code in **Cygwin terminal (bash)** with *command*:

```
g++.exe sol.cpp && ./a.exe < in.txt
```

prints the correct output:

```
START
Lorem Ipsum
Hello World
5
END
```

What is possibly the problem here?

Comment: You have one `cin.ignore()` but you may need two since Windows uses `\r\n`.

Comment: I retracted my close vote, I suppose your question requires better explanation of differences between systems (even emulated one like Cygwin)

Comment: I gues the proper way is to use the 2nd parameter: `cin.ignore(2, '\n');` That will ignore either 2 chars or until '\n' is reached.

Comment: I usually try to avoid mixing line-reading with field extraction

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. The answer was solved. As @Johnny Mopp in the comments above pointed out, Windows uses `\r\n` i.e. **carriage return** and **line feed** respectively while Unix use `\n` only, therefore in Windows one would need to write two `cin.ignore()` or `cin.ignore(2, '\n')` while in Unix one `cin.ignore()` will suffice.